# Getting values of dropdown django. (Also how to work with ranges when filtering)

Tags: django

I'm having problems trying to filter ranges and working with dropdowns.I will really appreciate any help with the two. 
Its dealing with age range.

1. Models.py :

```
class Part_Time_DM(models.Model):
    Name=models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, default="name") 
    Date_of_birth=models.DateField(default=date.today)
    Age=models.IntegerField()
```

2. Views.py:

```
def home(request):
   qs = Part_Time_DM.objects.all()

   location_query= request.GET.get('location')
   age_query= request.GET.get('age')

   if location_query != "" and location_query != None:

      qs = qs.filter(Location__icontains=location_query )

   return render(request, 'home.html', {"qs": qs})
```

3. Template:

```
<form class="form-wrap" method="GET" action=".">

                            <select name="age" class="form-control">
                                <option value="18 - 21">18 - 21</option>
                                <option value="22 - 25">22 - 25</option>
                                <option value="26 - 30">26 - 30</option>
                                <option value="31 - 35">31 - 35</option>
                                <option value="36 and above">36 and above</option>
                            </select>
                                                        <br>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                        </form>
```

Comment: have you tried printing `location_query` and `age_query` in views.py? tell us what you get, do you get some data or is it empty?

Comment: Location_query works just fine. The age_query is the problem. The `age_query` doesn't filter, instead it returns people from all ages.

Comment: so you mean you are not getting anything when you print `age_query`? Then try passing in simple numbers like 1,2,3 in the select dropdown value and then see what happens